# SCNShape not drawing with UIBezierPath under certain circumstances

Tags: ios, core-graphics, scenekit, uibezierpath, arkit

I believe this may be an iOS bug, and I've reported it to Apple via Bug Report. I'll post it here in case there's some workaround I can use, or explanation of the cause.

I'm wanting to draw the stroke of a UIBezierPath within SceneKit. I'm using the CGPath `copyStrokingWithWidth` function, and then creating a `SCNShape` using the given path.

This works fine for lines with 2 points, but on lines with 3 points, the SCNShape doesn't display anything. I've determined that this is only the case when the `lineWidth` is more than 0.1. With `lineWidth` set to 0.1, it displays perfectly.

```
let strokeBezierPath = UIBezierPath()
strokeBezierPath.lineWidth = 1
strokeBezierPath.move(to: CGPoint.zero)
strokeBezierPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 10, y: 0))
strokeBezierPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 10, y: 10))
let cgPath = strokeBezierPath.cgPath.copy(
    strokingWithWidth: strokeBezierPath.lineWidth,
    lineCap: strokeBezierPath.lineCapStyle,
    lineJoin: strokeBezierPath.lineJoinStyle,
    miterLimit: strokeBezierPath.miterLimit)

let bezierPath = UIBezierPath(cgPath: cgPath)
let shape = SCNShape(path: bezierPath, extrusionDepth: 1)
shape.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.blue
let node = SCNNode(geometry: shape)
node.position.z = -40

sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(node)
```

This works fine with:

- Just the first 2 points
- Line width of 0.1
- A manually-drawn bezier path covering the same area

Printing the UIBezierPath for line width as 0.1 (does display):

```
<UIBezierPath: 0x1d00b12e0; <MoveTo {0, 0.050000000000000003}>,
 <LineTo {10, 0.050000000000000003}>,
 <LineTo {9.9499999999999993, 10}>,
 <LineTo {10.050000000000001, 10}>,
 <LineTo {10.050000000000001, 0}>,
 <LineTo {0, -0.050000000000000003}>,
 <LineTo {0, 0.050000000000000003}>,
 <Close>
```

With line width as 0.2 (doesn't display):

```
<UIBezierPath: 0x1d00b7160; <MoveTo {0, 0.10000000000000001}>,
 <LineTo {10, 0.10000000000000001}>,
 <LineTo {9.9000000000000004, 0}>,
 <LineTo {9.9000000000000004, 10}>,
 <LineTo {10.1, 10}>,
 <LineTo {10.1, 0}>,
 <LineTo {10, -0.10000000000000001}>,
 <LineTo {0, -0.10000000000000001}>,
 <LineTo {0, 0.10000000000000001}>,
 <Close>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   let strokeBezierPath = UIBezierPath()
          strokeBezierPath.lineWidth = 1   
          strokeBezierPath.move(to: CGPoint.zero)
          strokeBezierPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 10, y: 0))
          strokeBezierPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 10, y: 10))
```

You haven’t closed the path. You won’t be able to extrude  two line segments that have not been closed... so nothing will appear. Close the path off with the following. This will bring up your geometry in the sceneView.

```
    strokeBezierPath.close()
```

Edit: Scenekit units are in metres. So to work with a smaller object in front of you. Change your units, and linewidth to the following. This will put the object 1 metre in front... and much smaller so you can see whats going on better.

```
let strokeBezierPath = UIBezierPath()
    strokeBezierPath.lineWidth = 0.01
    strokeBezierPath.move(to: CGPoint.zero)
    strokeBezierPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0.1, y: 0))
    strokeBezierPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0.1, y: 0.1))
    strokeBezierPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.1))
    strokeBezierPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))
    strokeBezierPath.close()
    let cgPath = strokeBezierPath.cgPath.copy(
        strokingWithWidth: strokeBezierPath.lineWidth,
        lineCap: strokeBezierPath.lineCapStyle,
        lineJoin: strokeBezierPath.lineJoinStyle,
        miterLimit: strokeBezierPath.miterLimit)

    let bezierPath = UIBezierPath(cgPath: cgPath)
    let shape = SCNShape(path: bezierPath, extrusionDepth: 0.01)
    shape.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.blue
    let node = SCNNode(geometry: shape)
    node.position.z = -1

    sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(node)
```

Comment: If I call `close()` on an open shape, such as my shape of 2 lines is, it creates a bezier path which "closes" the shape, in this case creating a triangular bezier path.

Comment: You only drew two lines. So the close path will create a triangular bezier path. In the second example, I added two more lines which draws a square bezier path.

Comment: Right. My goal right now is to draw an open shape, so 2 or 3 lines, which don't return to the start point.

Comment: Ok. But the bezier path will always have to close in scenekit... in order to create a surface to extrude.

Comment: Change the lineWidth from 0.01, 0.05, 0.1, 0.5  etc up to 1 ... and this will give  you idea how the line width effects the surface geometry when drawing shapes in scenekit. You need to set the lineWidth in proportion to the size of the geometry, otherwise, the width itself may be larger than the distance between points.