# (ARKit 2 Room Scanner) How to use UIBezierPath & featurePoints to create a node with the geometry of your surroundings with ARKit 2 & ARWorldMap

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, scenekit, arkit

I'm working with ARKit 2 and **ARWorldMapData** I have created a AR world that recognizes your surroundings with map data etc. from [link here](https://medium.com/@mohams3ios01/an-introduction-to-arkit-2-world-mapping-5b38827f8ec0). Now I am trying to figure out **how to take all the feature points and connect then to create a mesh** of my surroundings/ARWorldMap *(which has never been attempted before with ARKit 2 I think)*. Although I'm sure you can pull it off by connecting the feature points with a UIBezierPath. So that you can then use the shape the path creates as your nodes geometry.

**After Testing, the following code doesn't produce anything on the screen or at least I can't see it. So right now that's the problem. Although I'm sure there are may more issues with this.**

I pretty much just used the example in this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48628243/scnshape-not-drawing-with-uibezierpath-under-certain-circumstances) to see if It can remotely work.

**Code:**

```
func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didAdd node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor) {

guard !(anchor is ARPlaneAnchor) else { return }

let testNode = bezierNode.clone()

DispatchQueue.main.async {
    node.addChildNode(testNode)
}

}


func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, updateAtTime time: TimeInterval) {

// take the current frame/views features points and create an array out of them

guard let currentFrame = self.sceneView.session.currentFrame,
    let featurePointsArray = currentFrame.rawFeaturePoints?.points else { return }

// Create STROKE BezierPath

let strokeBezierPath = UIBezierPath()
strokeBezierPath.lineWidth = 0.1

 // Start the BezierPath at the first feature points on the screen

strokeBezierPath.move(to: CGPoint(x: CGFloat(featurePointsArray.first!.x), y: CGFloat(featurePointsArray.first!.y)))

// iterate through all feature pints and add then to the path

featurePointsArray.forEach { (pointLocation) in
    strokeBezierPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: CGFloat(pointLocation.x), y: CGFloat(pointLocation.y)))
}

// Close the Stroke BezierPath

strokeBezierPath.close()

// Do fancy work, not sure what this does

let cgPath = strokeBezierPath.cgPath.copy(
    strokingWithWidth: strokeBezierPath.lineWidth,
    lineCap: strokeBezierPath.lineCapStyle,
    lineJoin: strokeBezierPath.lineJoinStyle,
    miterLimit: strokeBezierPath.miterLimit)

// Create the actually bezierpath that were going to use to create the nodes geometry

let bezierPath = UIBezierPath(cgPath: cgPath)
let shape = SCNShape(path: bezierPath, extrusionDepth: 0.1)
shape.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.blue
let node = SCNNode(geometry: shape)

// Add newly created node to the reference that gets passed to the didAdd delegate


bezierNode = node

// Then anchor gets added when we touch the screen with a tap gesture temporary that call the didAdd delegate

}
```

**So that it pretty much could take a room like this and fill in the walls/points creating a mesh:**

[image]

**Result would look something like this, but obviously life size and in the perspective of actually standing in the room:**

[image]

**If any geniuses out there can help refactor my code, have better code than this or maybe know how to actually pull this off. That would be amazing!**. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ARWorldMap can store feature points, but more interestingly for you it will also save ARPlaneAnchors, which are essentially meshes already made up for you. the result won't be perfect but closer to what you are trying to achieve and much easier. I worked on this before and showed a video on twitter to present a visual ARWorldMap in a park, which gets extended (improved) each Time you launch the app in that location. ARKit can detect planes from feature points, the math is already done for you so use that instead of trying to link the feature points together.
  https://twitter.com/londonrom/status/1010150386848628736

Comment: Very interesting, your on the forefront I'll tell you that much. I looked at the link! super cool!. I'm still going to see if it's still possible to create a singular mesh. If not I most likely will mark this as the answer.